# Multiple case when in query with time duration (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am writing a query to retrieve data from a history table. History table captures all data from real-time table at the beginning of every month with an added 'capture_month' column. Trying to get the 'class_type' values captured on different months. Based on earnings of each account, their 'class_type' can change from A to D (A being good performer & D being bad performer)

```
Select
    account_id,
    case when capture_month::date = (date_trunc('month', current_date))::date THEN class_type END as [class_type_I_month_ago],
    case when capture_month::date = (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month')::date THEN class_type END as [class_type_II_months_ago],
    case when capture_month::date = (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '2 month')::date THEN class_type END as [class_type_III_months_ago]
from history_table
```

The result I get is

```
account_id | class_type_I_month_ago | class_type_II_months_ago | class_type_III_months_ago
 123456    |         A              |          [Null]          |       [Null]
 123456    |       [Null]           |            B             |       [Null]
 123456    |       [Null]           |          [Null]          |         B
```

How do I instead get them all in one line?

```
account_id | class_type_I_month_ago | class_type_II_months_ago | class_type_III_months_ago
 123456    |         A              |             B            |         B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need aggregation and group by

```
Select
    account_id,
    max(case when capture_month::date = (date_trunc('month', current_date))::date THEN class_type END) as [class_type_I_month_ago],
    max(case when capture_month::date = (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month')::date THEN class_type END ) as [class_type_II_months_ago],
    max(case when capture_month::date = (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '2 month')::date THEN class_type END) as [class_type_III_months_ago]
from history_table
group by account_id
```